# You must sign an apk with the same signature as the app you are trying to certify - blockchainds.com : How to sign an apk file by Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, apk, sign

In according documentation of blockchainds.com (an apk market) I must to download an apk prepared by the site and then sign this apk with same signature as my main app(that is uploaded).
My problem:How I sign an apk file. I get erros. I can sign my project with the same signature.Also I can'not resign my own apk yet.How we could sign an apk file(not project) in android studio 3.2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find details about signing an apk using android studio [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) You can check this [video tutorial also](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iH5Pawyw1n4). 
Now for signing the blank apk from blockchainds you need to go to the directory where java is installed. Open Command prompt and type `cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin` *(If you have changed the installation folder, use this same command but change the directory to the one you have selected during the installation of the SDK)*

type in the following command, but with the following arguments:

```
jarsigner -keystore <path to the keystore file> <path to the unsigned APK> <keystore alias>
```

Example: `jarsigner -keystore “C:\Users\Keystore\my_signature.jks" “C:\Users\Downloads\Unsigned_Test.apk” <your keystore alias name>`

You will be asked to insert the password for your Keystore file, type it down and press enter. **Your password is being inserted even if no text is shown!**

If everything went right, the unsigned APK will be signed and you can now submit it.

Comment: Thanks. In first part of your answer:I am not using the bundle and I want to sign an apk (no project or bundle).And about the jarsigner I will test it. Of course I tried with apksigner. I don't know is it valid to use jarsigner for an apk file(it seems jatsigner is designed for jar ...).However I will test it. 73

Comment: @maniaq it's valid to sign an apk with jarsigner. See the documentation on Android Developers site and Blockchainds. Developers are encouraged to use apksigner to sign the apk. This technique involves signing the apk file using the jarsigner command from the Java SDK